# Formatting based on Answer

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In a Sheet, I need to change the background color of a cell based on certain requirements. Logic:

> **If L2 does not have a date,** then

if date in D2 is before tomorrow, have no formatting in D2,
 if date in D2 is tomorrow, have yellow background in D2,
 if date in D2 is today, have red background in D2.

> **If L2 has a date,** then

have green background in D2.

This will be present through entire sheet.

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Sheets, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite certain what you want but would be happy to adjust the following a bit to suit. First, I suggest the whole column as easier for me to explain. Select D then Format, Conditional formatting..., Apply to range `D:D`, Format cells if..., **Custom formula is**

```
=and(L1="",D1=today()+1)
```

with yellow fill, <kbd>Done</kbd>. Then repeat but with:

```
=and(L1="",D1=today())
```

and red fill and also with:

```
=$L1<>""
```

and green fill.